# publish artifacts to multiple scp repository

Tags: jenkins, scp

I want to publish artifacts to multiple scp repository from Jenkins. Currently there is only one "publish artifacts to SCP repository" option under the post-build actions section in Jenkins. The plugin gives 1-1 option to publish artifacts to remote location.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Execute Shell" option and use SCP command to copy to multiple servers. That is the only options, Otherwise, configure one more job and call that job after this job is successful.

Answer (score -2):

[image: send build artifacts]

There's a post build action in Jenkins called **Send artifacts over SSH**, it's basically used to publish build artifacts but you can use it for your purpose.
Look at the bottom fo the screenshot, there's a button for adding another server where you can publish artifacts, serving the purpose!

**P.S:** *You should do a little bit of hands on / search online for such solutions before publishing them to stackoverflow.*

Comment: I don't see such a post build job. Does it come with a plugin?

Comment: @nurp yeah it's a plugin, someone from community has already posted a blog on it - sorry I didn't mention that http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-sshdeploy